# MacOS for Beginners - Which Tools to Install?

Tags: osx, productivity, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, macos

I've been a programmer for quite some time and therefore I had a lot of contact with Windows (vomit - I have to have it to play games), Linux (yeah), and lately I started with MacOS just to learn more about it. I love the terminal since I've been in contact with Linux. Nevertheless there are some basic toolings besides the console you still need for the daily stuff.

I have installed a couple of things that I like:

- [Flycut: copy paste history](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut)
- [Caffeine: to stop standby](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)
- [Homebrew: linux like paket manager](https://brew.sh/index_de)
- [Bartender: to hide system tray icons](https://www.macbartender.com/)
- [Atom: nice plugin based editor](https://atom.io/)
- [Alfred App: spotlight replacement (non paid - which really is nah. Is there a good alternative?)](https://www.alfredapp.com/)
- [CheatSheet: to remember or don't remember the shortcuts](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/?lang=de)
- [GIMP: graphic editing](https://www.gimp.org)
- Firefox & Thunderbird obviously
- Greenshot - which is windows based only: Alternatives?

I was recommended in comment by @Dɑvïd this [summary](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82/136150) and already looked up cyberduck for FTP + quicksilver as an Alfred alternative.

Any other suggestions on must-haves on MacOS?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for [the Q&A format on this site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but time will tell. Meanwhile, you should check this Q&A on Apple.Stackexchange: "[Which OS X Applications do you find indispensable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/82/136150)"

Comment: @Dɑvïd I see your point. I'm not sure either, this is the first time for me on this community. Thanks for the great link! :)

Comment: “List of apps” is off-topic here. On this site you list requirements and constraints, then we provide a specific solution meeting your needs. I suggest taking this to a discussion-oriented site, such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/

Comment: @BasilBourque I am aware of that. I list them because I want them to be excluded from the answers as well as give you my "requirements" on a high level. If I ask can you list me tools that increase productivity, is that enough for you? :)

Answer (score 1):

A popular code editor is **Visual Studio Code**. It is a free offering from the vomit company (I hate them too but VScode is a very nice app). There are 100's of extensions for many different programming languages and other mods to VScode. Don't confuse Visual Studio Code with Visual Studio.

An inexpensive app that I use occasionally is ***Pages***. Its Macs replacement for MS Word but scaled done some. It may come with your Mac but if not it is free from the App Store.

Along with Pages is the Macs replacement for Excel. This app is called **Numbers** and is also free from the app store if not already on your machine.

Another free app I use a lot is **iTerm**. This is a terminal emulator for the Mac. Since Mac is based on Unix, iTerm lets you take full advantage of that. Macs come with their own Terminal emulator called Terminal but I find iTerm more useful.

My last suggestion only applies if you want to program in Python. I would recommend the **Anaconda** Python distribution. It comes with a free Python IDE called Spyder. A very nice IDE and is close to Visual Studio Code for Python programming.

I have over a hundred Mac apps on my computer but the ones above are the ones I use the most. I'm sure others will have more suggestions.